# Issue with RVM in Nitrous.io's console

Tags: rvm, nitrousio

**RVM** is pre-installed in **Nitrous.io** but when I type `rvm get stable` or `rvm list` I'm getting `-bash: rvm: command not found`. What's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RVM used to be pre-installed, not any more. Recently they switched to using Chruby to manage Ruby versions.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on information if you still wanted to go with rvm

Glad to help. The steps I followed to resolve the issue on Nitrous are :

1. gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
   This Installs gpg signatures. rvm has started enforcing GPG signing about 3-4 days back (wayneeseguin/rvm#3110). Looks like a necessary step from now for all new rvm installations.

Steps 2 & 3 are unique to Nitrous.io and are a result of error messages during the rvm install.

2. unset GEM_HOME
3. added source ~/.profile to .bash_profile

followed by the rvm install steps

4. $ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles --ruby
5. source /home/action/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work successfully with the tweaks below

To do step 3 :
source ~/.bashrc
Type source ~/.profile
Then type exit

Do Step 4 above

Step 5 now needs to be changed to: 
source /home/nitrous/.rvm/scripts/rvm